# Display the numerical index order of results in mySQL as a additional column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

First q ever Whohoo!

I have a mySQL table with data

```
**username**   **score**   
Count Joe         278     
Count Joe         255
Count Joe         298
Count Joe         289
```

I am having problems displaying the following result set:

```
**RANK** **USERNAME** **SCORE**
1 Count Joe 255
2 Count Joe 278
3 Count Joe 289
4 Count Joe 298
```

Currently it is returning

```
**RANK** **USERNAME** **SCORE**
    1 Count Joe 255
    22 Count Joe 278
    32 Count Joe 289
    18 Count Joe 298
```

Using

`SET @ROW=0;
SELECT @ROW:=@ROW + 1 AS rank, username, total FROM game_scores GROUP BY username ORDER BY total ASC LIMIT 10`

The query above seems to return the index position or the user within the queried table.

Comment: What is your desired output? Your query will put pseudo-row numbers on the result set (if you initialize @row to 0 before the query) -- isn't that what you want?

Comment: @DMac
Just edited that. Forgot to add it to the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS rank, s1.*
FROM
(
    SELECT   username, score
    FROM     scores    
    GROUP BY username ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 10
) AS s1
JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
```

Comment: Hi Tony.
Thanx for the answer, that unfortunately returns the same result set as my query.
I have update the question by be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Edited answer. Try it.